# Unity C#: HMAC Initialization throws and error. How to solve it

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, encryption, cryptography

Getting a null reference exception when decrypting a string using AES in Unity android build. Its some HMAC Initialize error.

I have used system.cryptorgraphy's AES encryption and decryption algorithm to use encryption in my game and I am getting the error on Android devices. Does anyone have idea about What HMAC Initialise() is and how to solve this error? I have pasted the code which I am using to to decrypt.

The screenshot of the error is all attached below.

```
public  string Decrypt (string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "abc123";
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace (" ", "+");
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (cipherText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create ()) {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes (EncryptionKey, new byte[] {
            0x49,
            0x76,
            0x61,
            0x6e,
            0x20,
            0x4d,
            0x65,
            0x64,
            0x76,
            0x65,
            0x64,
            0x65,
            0x76
        });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes (32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes (16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ()) {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream (ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor (), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                cs.Write (cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close ();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString (ms.ToArray ());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

[image]

I am very new to Stackoverflow, I tried finding duplicates but I failed. Please provide the link if you think the question is duplicate.

Comment: I recommend you read [how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then quickly edit your question accordingly before it get downvoted and burried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, going thru it.

Comment: HMAC is used *within* Rfc2898DeriveBytes to generate the key from a given password (and salt). That doesn't explain why it hasn't been initialized though. And neither does it explain why a hash is first called and then HMAC. The only idea I can give you is that there is also a constructor that additionally takes an iteration count (an integer behind your static salt value, say set to 40,000 or so). Note that static salts are next to useless.

Comment: I got the solution. I was getting null ref because to use HMAC .Net2.0 uses reflection and when I was making a build the i was using .Net 2.0 subset and I was stripping all the codes needed to use cryptography. Thanks for the comment @MaartenBodewes

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I was getting null ref because, to use HMAC .Net2.0 uses reflection and when I was making a build the i was using .Net 2.0 subset and I was stripping all the codes needed to use cryptography.